# Circular relationship with behavioursubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am listening to changes in a behaviourSubject, and then transforming the data before I update the behaviourSubject with the changed data. This creates a circle. What is a better practice for doing this?

```
private dataBehaviourSubject: BehaviourSubject<Data[]> 
   = new BehaviourSubject<Data[]>(this._data);

private _data = []

private get data$() {
    return this.dataBehaviourSubject.asObservable();
}

private updateBehaviourSubject(updatedData) {
   // update this._data with updatedData
   this.dataBehaviourSubject.next(this._data);
}

public addData(newData) {
   this._data.push(newData)
   this.dataBehaviourSubject.next(this._data);
} 

data$.pipe(
   map(oldData => { //transform. Perhaps fetch and append data } )
).subscribe(updateBehaviourSubject(updatedData))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by defining your `data$` observable to be derived from your "data input" and use the `scan` operator to emit the updated state based on the previous state and the new input.  This can all be done without  subscribing.

```js
private dataInput$ = new ReplaySubject<DataInput>(1); // like BehaviorSubject, but with no initial emission

public data$: Observable<Data[]> = this.dataInput$.pipe(
    scan((previous, input) => {
        // return a value to be emitted based on the
        // previous value and the current input.
        return previous.concat(input);
    }, [])
);

public addData(newData) {
   this.dataInput.next(newData);
}
```

Here `data$` will emit the updated state whenever `dataInput$` emits a new value.  If the modifications you need to make are synchronous, the above code will work fine.  However, if they come from other observable sources, you will need to use `mergeMap` first:

```js
public data$: Observable<Data[]> = this.dataInput$.pipe(
    mergeMap(input => this.getSomeOtherData(input)),
    scan((previous, someOtherData) => {
        return // return something meaningful
    }, INITIAL_DATA),
    // startWith(INITIAL_DATA) // use startWith if you want to emit an initial value (in case inputData$ hasn't emitted yet
);
```

Here `mergeMap` will subscribe to the `getSomeOtherData` observable and emit it's emisison(s) into the `scan` operator.

Notice there are less moving parts here, its simply a subject, and a single derived observable.  This approach avoids the circular issue you were having but, it also has the benefit of being completely lazy: if there no subscribers to `data$` then the "fetch" logic will not be executed.